# Pass ViewBag Values from Razor View to Controller using HTML.Begin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

How can I pass a value in ViewBag to controller via `HTML.BeginForm()`?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveServiceItemCategory", "Admin", 
                       FormMethod.Post, new { Sku = @ViewBag.SkuCategory  }))
{
    <span>Service Item Sku : @ViewBag.SkuCategory</span>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SaveServiceItemCategory(FormCollection formCollection, 
                                            string Sku)
{}
```

I am getting Sku as null, and not the value in ViewBag.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no variant of `BeginForm` that accepts values to be posted.

The `IDictionary` collection parameter for `BeginForm` is for `htmlAttributes`. Check your HTML code and you'll probably see an attribute on the form named `Sku`. These attributes don't get posted to the server.

You need to create a form element to contain your data to be posted.

```
@Html.Hidden("Sku", @ViewBag.SkuCategory);
```

Comment: This does not seem to post to the server. Only items from the model are posting.

Comment: All form fields are posted. The default binder might not attach them to the model specified but you'll see they're available in the FormCollection.